# How can we create our own string encoding-decoding or encryption-decryption script in java without using any given library i.e. Base64, AES, etc?

Tags: java, security, encryption, encoding, cryptography

How can we create our own string encoding-decoding or encryption-decryption script in **java** without using any given library i.e. Base64, AES, etc?

As per my client requirements, he want something where a user can decide a particular letter/number to be replaced by a letter/number which is again choosed by the same user. So I jsut want to make it confirm that is there any possibilities to do so? **Any suggestion will be appreciated!**

Comment: This is a cipher, and should not be trusted for any kind of security.

Comment: @Seiyria, can you please explain...why?

Comment: Maintaining a HashMap of Key(the value getting replaced) with a value(the value to be replaced) and just changing the string using a simple function will do.

Comment: @UmaKanth thanks for your suggestion, in this way we can do encoding/encrption, perfect ......but how decoding/decrption will take place? Can you please show some example code.....because i m not perfect in java yet! But the client requirement is killing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintaining a HashMap of Key(the value getting replaced) with a value(the value to be replaced) and just changing the string using a simple function will do.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
public class Encrypt {

/**
 * @param args
 */
static HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    hm.put("a", "b");   
    hm.put("b", "c");   
    hm.put("c", "d");   
    hm.put("d", "e");   
    hm.put("e", "f");   
    hm.put("f", "g");
    hm.put("g", "h");   
    hm.put("h", "i");   
    hm.put("i", "j");   
    hm.put("j", "k");   
    hm.put("k", "l");   
    hm.put("l", "m");
    hm.put("m", "n");   
    hm.put("1", "4");   
    hm.put("2", "3");   
    hm.put("3", "2");   
    hm.put("4", "1");   
    hm.put("5", "0");

    String input = "this is a simple text";
    String text = encode(input);
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println(decode(text));

}

private static String decode(String input) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        String ch = input.charAt(i)+"";
        if(hm.containsValue(ch))
        {
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue().equals(ch)) {
                    output.append(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}

private static String encode(String input) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        String ch = input.charAt(i)+"";
        if(hm.containsKey(ch))
        {
            output.append(hm.get(ch));
        }
        else
        {
            output.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

}

**EDIT**

This is not recommended, as if someone breaks the sequence he could easily know all the text.

Comment: thanks for your support...let me try. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: This has identical security to a Vigenère cipher (or less). If this is acceptable then your client must still live in the Renaissance. Single substitution ciphers are considered *classic* ciphers for a reason.

Comment: I do agree with @maarteenbodewes, This is easily breakable. I don't know what your client wants but DES, SHA are considered to be the best and literally impossible to crack.

Comment: DES & SHA are however just last century, so we're getting closer to the present. It's AES and SHA-2 now, using authenticated encryption. SHA-3 is almost standardized, but there is no reason to switch yet.

Comment: No, making it clear that i do use other encrption too....like on 1st level, data will be encrypted using client specified method first then on second level i am using other encrption methods(after that data will be stored in app database) and later on at last level of encrption i am again encrypting the data before saving it into the server database. SO it has 3 level of data protection. Now coming to the client, my client was not happy with the encryption methods we usualy use......he want something where he can choose the first level of encryption.